# Excel formula to verify cell and skip to next row

Tags: excel, if-statement

It is possible the answer is an `if` statement. Here is the question.

Column A:

```
ABC
ABC
XYX
XYX
AAA
```

Column B:

```
12
22
1
23
3
```

Column C:

```
If Cell A = ABC
    then display Column B
If Cell A isn't ABC
    then go to next row.
```

Question 1:

I would like the formula to check `A1`, `A2`, etc. and return result in `C1`, `C2`, etc. with value equals to `B1`, `B2`.

Question 2:

Just say `A8` is the last entry, and `A9` is blank. Is there a formula to know to stop if `A1` is blank and stop validation?

Comment: Please share some sample data and/or a screenshot.

Comment: @petersmith - I am trying to have separate tab for each company name. if I drag it down on each page, there will be blank spot. how can I avoid it?